# Elements event handler into EXT.js panel

Tags: javascript, extjs

In my application I need a panel that has HTML elements like radio button and checkbox.

For wrapping elements (radio button and etc.) with EXT panel I put these elements into a variable and put this variable into HTML feature of EXT panel.

**CODE**

```
var p = new Ext.Panel({
    title: 'OptionsPanel',
    collapsible:true,
    preventBodyReset: true,
    renderTo: 'options',
    width:400,
    html: html.join('')
});
var html = [
'<ul id="controlToggle">',
'<li>',
        '<input type="radio" name="type" value="none" id="noneToggle" class="toggle"  checked="checked"  >',
        '<label for="noneToggle">navigate</label>',
    '</li>',

    '<li>',
        '<input type="radio" name="type" value="polygon" id="polygonToggle" class="toggle"  >',
        '<label for="polygonToggle">draw polygon</label>',
    '</li>',

    '<li>',
        '<input type="radio" name="type" value="modify" id="modifyToggle" class="toggle"  >',
        '<label for="modifyToggle">modify feature</label>',
    '</li>',
        '<ul>',
            '<li>',
                '<input id="createVertices" type="checkbox" checked="" name="createVertices" class="update">',
                '<label for="createVertices">allow vertices creation</label>',
            '</li>',
            '<li>',
                '<input id="rotate" type="checkbox" name="rotate" class="update">',
                '<label for="rotate">allow rotation</label>',
            '</li>',
            '<li>',
                '<input id="resize" type="checkbox" name="resize" class="update">',
                '<label for="resize">allow resizing</label>',
                '(<input id="keepAspectRatio" type="checkbox" name="keepAspectRatio" class="update" checked="checked">',
                '<label for="keepAspectRatio">keep aspect ratio</label>)',
            '</li>',
            '<li>',
                '<input id="drag" type="checkbox" name="drag" class="update">',
                '<label for="drag">allow dragging</label>',
            '</li>',
        '</ul>',
    '</li>',
    '</ul>'
];
```

I control my map behaviors with this HTML elements in the EXT panel. For this reason when user clicks a radio button I use jQuery to understand that it was clicked.

**jQuery**

```
$(".toggle").click(function(){
    for(key in controls) {
        var control = controls[key];
        if($(this).val() == key && $(this).is(":checked")) {
            control.activate();
        } else {
            control.deactivate();
        }
    }
});
```

But jQuery can't select toggle class because it is in a Javascript variable into EXT panel.

My question is, how can I select HTML elements in Javascript variables into an EXT panel? In other words, how can I use event handlers for putting HTML elements into an EXT panel.

The handler function is defined in the Javascript code.

Comment: Not sure I edited that just right.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things to consider:

1. Why don't you use ExtJs visual elements like Ext.form.field.Radio http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Radio and Ext.form.field.Checkbox http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Checkbox
2. If you really want to use plain HTML elements inside ExtJs - that's fine too. But in order to subscribe to their events you actually need to wait until they will be rendered. So you first need to subscribe to `render` event of your panel. And in the handler find HTML elements (by their Id or by type of whatever) and add listener to their events. But I would recommend to go with #1.

Comment: If i use #1 for a radio button can i use event handler that handle a java script function.In Jquery i use this code $(".update").change(update); that update is a function How can i do this in Extjs?

Comment: Absolutely - check how to configure listeners for example: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Radio-cfg-listeners